# Make Class iterable with a for in Loop?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom class:

```
class MyArrayClass {
...
}
```

This class is a custom list implementation.

I want to do the following:

```
var arr:MyArrayClass = MyArrayClass()
arr.append("first")
arr.append("second")
arr.append("third")

for entry in arr {
  println("entry: \(entry)")
}
```

Edit: The class I want to make iterable is [JavaUtilArrayList](https://gist.github.com/steffimueller/b48d64303f2579b86a5a) it uses this class [IOSObjectArray](https://gist.github.com/steffimueller/4df7775bc455a60e2148).

**Which protocol must be confirmed by my class such that it works in a for in loop?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it much faster using `NSFastGenerator`:

```
extension MyArrayClass: SequenceType {
  public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
    return NSFastGenerator(self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/swift-sequences) blog post on this exact topic. I'll write a summary of it here though:

When you write:

```
// mySequence is a type that conforms to the SequenceType protocol.
for x in mySequence {
    // iterations here
}
```

Swift converts this to:

```
var __g: Generator = mySequence.generate()
while let x = __g.next() {
    // iterations here
}
```

Therefore, to be able to enumerate through your custom type you need to make your class implement the `SequenceType` protocol too. Looking at the `SequenceType` protocol below, you can see you only need to implement one method that returns an object that conform to the `GeneratorType` protocol (`GeneratorType` is covered in the blog post).

```
protocol SequenceType : _Sequence_Type {
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType
    func generate() -> Generator
}
```

Here's an example of how to make `MyArrayClass` useable in a `for` loop:

```
class MyArrayClass {
    var array: [String] = []

    func append(str: String) {
        array.append(str)
    }
}

extension MyArrayClass : SequenceType {
    // IndexingGenerator conforms to the GeneratorType protocol.
    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<Array<String>> {
        // Because Array already conforms to SequenceType,
        // you can just return the Generator created by your array.
        return array.generate()
    }
}
```

Now to use this in practise:

```
let arr = MyArrayClass()
arr.append("first")
arr.append("second")
arr.append("third")

for x in arr {
    println(x)
}

// Prints:
//     First
//     Second
//     Third
```

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Could you also post an example how to use it in a Extension of ``MyClass``?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my edit. The class which I wanna make iterable with an extension is JavaUtilArrayList se above. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of those classes I'm afraid.