# Cast Entry in For in Loop over SequenceType?

Tags: ios, swift

Having the following for in loop:

```
for entry in entries {
   println("entry: \(entry)")
}
```

I want to cast the entry in the loop header to String. I **cannot** do the following because it is no Array:

```
for entry in entries as! [String] {
}
```

because entries is not an array.

Edit: entries conforms the `SequenceType`protocol.

How can I cast entry in the loop header to String?

Comment: Do you mean that `entries` is not of an array type (like it is `AnyObject`), or is it not an array at all (like an integer, an instance of a class, etc.)

Comment: @Antonio entries conforms the SequenceType protocol but is no array.

Comment: If `entries`'s class conforms to `SequenceType` you shouldn't need to cast it to an array to iterate through it...

Comment: @stephan1001:  If it's not an array then you cannot cast into an array - you should probably try converting before the loop

Comment: Is this related to your previous question? (A self-contained example would be useful). – Why does the next() function of the generator not return the correct type? – What about `for entry : String in entries { ... }` ?

Comment: @Antonio I wrote that I cannot do that. So it is not an array.

Comment: @MartinR because it is AnyObject.

Comment: @stephan1001: And do you know that *all* object from the iteration are strings? Or do you want to iterate over strings only?

Comment: @stephan1001: I just interpreted that as "I want to do a cast, but it doesn't work" - my misunderstanding

Comment: @Antonio Yes all elements are Strings!

Comment: @stephan1001: The real question is: Why does your generator return AnyObject and not String? Can you show your code?

Comment: It is code from Objective-C from a third party api. I do not control the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's map for that ;-)

```
let entries = NSSet(array: ["Foo", "Bar"])

for entry in map(entries, {$0 as! String}) {
    println("entry: \(entry)")
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `map()` is also a good idea (didn't think of that). However, it returns an *array*, not a sequence, therefore a better method *may be* `for entry in lazy(entries).map( {$0 as! String}) { ... }` .

Comment: @MartinR What is the difference between Matteo's solution and yours?

Comment: Are your solutions effizient?

Comment: @stephan1001: `map()` creates an *array* of all elements, not a sequence. That might be acceptable or not (only you can decide). You would get a similar result with `let a = Array(entries) ; for x in a as! [String] { ... }` (see update of my answer). – `lazy(entries).map()` creates a *sequence*, the code in my answer creates a sequence as well, the advantage can be that no array containing all elements is allocated. – As I already said, the best solution would be if you modify your generator to return strings in the first place.

Comment: @stephan1001 you know ... early optimisation is evil. I would use it since it appears clearer the intent to me. Hopefully the compiler will optimise it. You can check it out in -O fast mode ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The "easy" solution would be

```
for x in entries {
    if let y = x as? String {
        println(y)
    }
}
```

but that is probably not what you are looking for.

---

If it is acceptable that an *array* of all elements is created first
then the following would work as well:

```
let a = Array(entries)
for x in a as! [String] {
    println(x)
}
```

---

If `entries` is a sequence producing `AnyObject` elements, and you
*know* that all these elements are in fact strings, then you can
create a new sequence producing `String`s with

```
let stringSeq = SequenceOf { () -> GeneratorOf<String> in
    var gen = entries.generate()
    return GeneratorOf {
        return gen.next() as? String
    }
}

for x in stringSeq {
    println(x) // x is a `String`
}
```

---

What you probably should do is to change the definition of the
`entries` generator itself  so that it produces strings in the first place. Example (based on the code in your previous
question [Make Class iterable with a for in Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080998/make-class-iterable-with-a-for-in-loop) and [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/swift-sequences) blog post):

```
// Class containing an array of `AnyObject`:
class MyArrayClass {
    var array: [AnyObject] = ["a", "b", "c"]
}

// Sequence producing `String`:
extension MyArrayClass : SequenceType {
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<String> {
        var index = 0
        return GeneratorOf {
            if index < self.array.count {
                return self.array[index++] as? String
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}

// Now the enumeration gives strings:
let entries = MyArrayClass()
for x in entries {
    println(x)
}
```